# Set ImageView to a drawable (Android)

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

Forgive me for being new to and my teminology may be incorrect:

I have an array of images in class1, when an image is selected its id is passed to class2 (code below) I then display that image and give the option to set it as a wallpaper.  The problem is, using the code below I need the a drawable to assign the wallpaper, not ImageView.  Can someone give me some guidance in referencing the actual drawable where I have 
"myWallpaperManager.setResource(need a drawable here);"

Thanks in advance.  Hope this makes sense, as I said I am a noob!

```
public class FullWallView extends Activity {
private Button wallbutton;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.wallpaper_full);

    // get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image id
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_wall_view);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);

    //Making Button Clickable and setting the wallpaper
    wallbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.apply);
    wallbutton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
    {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
             = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                myWallpaperManager.setResource(need a drawable here);
            } catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
            }

           }});
```

Comment: I ended up doing this:
       final Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();

Then I changed to:
myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap); 
it seems to be a bit slow, but it is working now.

Answer (score 35):

First define the Drawable, then set it in an ImageView.

```
img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imageView1);
img.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);
```

Comment: One more point, if anyone requires `getResources()` in custom adapter class, use `context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imageView1);` where `Context context;` and is passed in constructor from calling `Activity/Fragment`

Answer (score 12):

[getResources().getDrawable(int id)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable(int)) method was deprecated in API level 22.

You can check version then use these methods:

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
       imageView.setImageDrawable(getApplicationContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.myDrawable));
  } else {
      imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myDrawable));
    }
```

.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this dynamically by only supplying the image name :

```
public static Drawable getImage(Context context, String name) {
    return context.getResources().getDrawable(context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", context.getPackageName()));
}
```

then set the imagedrawable like this :

```
ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.logo);
image.setImageDrawable(getImage(context, "imageName"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just noticed that you need to pass resourceID not Drawable, there is no direct way to get resourceID from ImageView, why don't you try to remember this value and then pass it.

Hope this helps and enjoy your work

Comment: so Drawable drawable1 = imageView.getDrawable();
Then myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.drawable1); down below?

Comment: No, I didn't saw that it needs to be ResourceID, not Drawable. See edited answer.